# How to use React-Router in a Slider

Tags: hyperlink, slider, react-router

First, show the UI.

[image: The UI show]

When I touchMove the handler and touchEnd, I want to change the url, like before changing is `.../component` and after changing the url will became `.../component?range=[0,1000]`

----- more detail -----

```
var RangeSlider = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="range-slider-module">
        <div className="range-slider-area">
          <div ref="filledRange" className="range-slider-filled"></div>  {/* This div show the target range selected*/}
            <div onTouchStart={this.handleMouseDown}
                 onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                 onClick={this.handleClick}
                 ref="handlerLeft"
                 className="range-slider-handler-left">
            </div> {/* Left handler */}
            <div onTouchStart={this.handleMouseDown}
                 onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                 onClick={this.handleClick}
                 ref="handlerRight"
                 className="range-slider-handler-right">
            </div> {/* Right handler */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
})
```

[image: moreDetial]

Comment: to change the URL you would use `this.push('/yourNewPath')`, show what you've done so far it would be easier to help you.

Comment: problem description has been updated, hope your new apply